# Object reference not found for IAuthenticationManager

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am getting this error in my MVC Application

> The type or namespace name 'IAuthenticationManager' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Following is my code where I am getting Error

```
private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
{
   get
   {
       return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add Reference to this DLL shown in the link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.iauthenticationmanager(v=vs.113).aspx

It comes from the assembly **Microsoft.Owin.dll**

> 1. Check your Nuget Package references if you installed through Nuget
> 2. If not, install through Nuget package to get the assembly reference. The package name - **Microsoft.Owin**